# How to get the length of a class array in C++, without hardcoding?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have a class array in C++. I have defined it as such:

```
Student* pliststudent = new Student[2]{ 3,5 };
```

I know that the class array decays into a pointer when we assign it to `Student* pliststudent`.

It becomes difficult to extract the length of the class array, without hardcoding it.

I implemented the code, such that it is not hardcoded (using friend function). But I think, a better solution must exist.

Following is my full code:

```cpp
    class Student
    {
    private:
        int marks;
        int counter=0;
    public:
        Student(int marks) : marks(marks)
        {}

        int FinalMarks()
        {
            marks *=2;
            return marks;
        }

        friend int Length(Student ob1, Student ob2);
    };

    int Length(Student ob1, Student ob2)
    {
        int i = ++ob1.counter + ++ob2.counter;
        return i;
    }

    int main()
    {
        Student* pliststudent = new Student[2]{ 3,5 };
        //int length = sizeof(*pliststudent) / sizeof(pliststudent[0]); //This does not work.

        int length = Length(pliststudent[0], pliststudent[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            cout << (pliststudent+i)->FinalMarks() << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Is there a better solution to this? I don't want to hardcode the size of the Student class array.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `std::vector<Student> pliststudent = {3, 5};`. Once you do that, then none of those "length" computations are necessary, or shenanigans with `friend` functions.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `Length` function at all. It will always output `2`, if used only once on objects. Otherwise it returns larger values that are not related to the array length at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get the length of an array from a pointer to the array's first element.  That information is lost when the array decays to a pointer.

You need to keep the length information somewhere, either yourself:

```
int length = 2;
Student* pliststudent = new Student[length]{ 3,5 };
```

or by using a container that tracks the length for you:

```
std::vector<Student> students{3, 5};
// students.size() returns the number of Student objects in the vector
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d3056100a9ef109)

Answer (score 4):

If you must use a dynamic array, there is no way to automatically determine the size of the array. That information is "lost" when storing the array in a pointer as you have done.

There are several ways to work around this, the preferred one is the one already suggested in the comments, use `std::vector<Student>` instead. Vector is the standard library's dynamic array and is almost always what you want. And since it takes care of the memory management automatically, it is much simpler to work with.

However, if you *must* use dynamic arrays, (because this is a school assignment and you are not allowed to use `std::vector`), then you should store the size of the array in a separate variable, and pass that together with whatever you need to do.

```
const int nStudents = 2;
Student* pliststudents = new Student[nStudents]{3, 5};
```